# How does fogbugz do the "Add Case" ajax?

Tags: ajax, fogbugz

I really like how FogBugz has an "Add Case" button where it instantly adds the text you entered into the table, and gives you the ability to add another one.

Does anybody know how it is done? or ideally, does anyone have any snippets for PHP/MYSQL system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it very easily with jQuery.

When you click the "tick" an AJAX query is submitted, then a new row is added to the table.

If you already have PHP code for adding a record to the your mySQL database it is just a matter of learning some jQuery.

There are lots of tutorials on the jQuery site. [Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Rate_me:_Using_Ajax) is a good tutorial on basic AJAX.